# use XML::Smart to get Perl arrays from an XML element with multiple children?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

Given this XML file snippet:

```
<properties>
  <one>ONE</one>
  <two>TWO</two>
  <three>THREE</three>
</properties>
```

I want these two arrays:

```
(ONE, TWO, THREE)
(one, two, three)
```

Or a hash is also appropriate. If it's possible, I want to use [`XML:Smart`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSmart) because I am already using it a lot.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly tried it out with XML::Smart. This code works.

```
use strict;
use feature qw(say);
use XML::Smart;
my %config;

my $str = qq~<properties>
  <one>ONE</one>
  <two>TWO</two>
  <three>THREE</three>
</properties>~;

my $XML = XML::Smart->new($str);
my @nodes = $XML->{properties}->nodes();
foreach my $k (@nodes) {
  say "$k: ", $k->key;
  $config{$k} = $k->key;
}
print Dumper \%config;
```

It will print the following:

```
ONE: one
TWO: two
THREE: three
$VAR1 = {
          'TWO' => 'two',
          'THREE' => 'three',
          'ONE' => 'one'
        };
```

It's all in the documentation: [key-method](http://search.cpan.org/~gmpassos/XML-Smart-1.6.9/lib/XML/Smart.pm#key%28%29), [nodes-method](http://search.cpan.org/~gmpassos/XML-Smart-1.6.9/lib/XML/Smart.pm#nodes%28%29)

Putting it in two arrays seems to be harder. Maybe have a look at the [i()-method](http://search.cpan.org/~gmpassos/XML-Smart-1.6.9/lib/XML/Smart.pm#i%28%29).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple) to parse the XML. Then simply extract the key/value pairs to arrays.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use XML::Simple;

my $file = shift;
my $xml  = XMLin($file);   # $xml is now a hash ref with the data

my @keys = keys %$xml;     # extract hash keys
my @vals = values %$xml;   # extract hash values

print Dumper \@keys, \@vals;
```

Comment: Thanks, nice to know how XML::Simple works. Please let the solution be on site. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for introducing me to XML::Smart. It had passed me by, and seems to be a whole lot better than the ubiquitous XML::Simple.

It looks like you need to access the XML as a hash. That is like XML::Simple, but in this case the hash is a tied one instead of a real one so that the implementation can be much more sturdy.

Use the `nodes` method to access the list of nodes inside the `<properties>` element, and fetch the tag name and text content of each element with `key` and `content`.

Here is some code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Smart;

my $xml = <<'XML';
<properties>
  <one>ONE</one>
  <two>TWO</two>
  <three>THREE</three>
</properties>
XML

my $smart = XML::Smart->new($xml);

my @nodes = $smart->{properties}->nodes;
my @text = map $_->content, @nodes;
my @names = map $_->key, @nodes;

printf "(%s)\n", join ', ', @text;
printf "(%s)\n", join ', ', @names;
```

**output**

```
(ONE, TWO, THREE)
(one, two, three)
```

Comment: +1 because I actualy like your solution better than mine. I didn't get the array first of, but this way does.